# Standard Entities in Watson Knowledge Studio Custom Model

Tags: watson

I have built a custom model for identifying customer specific entities in Watson Knowledge Studio. Can i leverage and reuse standard entities (e.g. Email) which are part of the standard model in the custom model without having to redefine them from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and found the info below - more details are at: https://watson-tricks.blogspot.com/

Post titled - "Combining the annotation capabilities of both Watson Knowledge Studio and Watson Discovery Service"

"It is not feasible for users to build a complete WKS model that incorporates all of the normal language dictionaries as well as the specialized domain terminology. However, there is a trick which can be used to get WDS to use both the domain specific annotator from WKS and the generic language annotator from WDS.
Unfurtunately this trick is not possible with the normal WDS UI, but it requires the use of the REST API"

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find enrichment for NLU. However i simply called the Analyze request two times, once with a custom model for Entities and second time without it. Got two JSON's and will combine the two to get a final list of entities. Not cost effective though as the number of requests will increase

Comment: Is this really the answer?

Comment: I don't think this is the solution, but a workaround